# Script led to "Invalid syntax" in terminal but fine when run a script file

Tags: python-3.x

Running a script written in a .py file via terminal works fine, but when I ran this script in terminal after turning on python it doesn't work anymore (please see code below).

I'm a beginner. Just learnt how to define a function, but this function only works when I write it in a .py script file run by terminal.

i.e. It doesn't work if I directly type in the same lines of code in terminal; instead terminal returns "Invalid Syntax". I tried both python2 and python3; the issue remains nonetheless.

Can someone please let me know why this could be the case? Thank you very much!

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> def plus_ten(a):
...     return a+10
... plus_ten(2)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    plus_ten(2)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expect that terminal would return 12.

Comment: After defining the function first left the code indentation by hitting enter two times without type any new line code and then try to call `plus_ten(2)`

Comment: REPL needs to run one statement at a time. After function end, hit enter until you get `>>>` again. Then call the function.

Comment: Wait for the prompt '>>>' to type next command / instruction

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone, for providing answers. They have solved my question effectively. I want to vote/score/like for your answers. I googled/"Youtubed" but can't seem to find how I can achieve that without earning sth called "the appropriate voting privilege". Is that true? Again, thank you for your help, indeed!

Comment: They only commentted on your question, that's why you cannot mark their answers as accepted...

Comment: Thank you @olinox14. Does that mean there's nothing (like giving a thumb up) I can do to these comments?

Comment: No, but that's nice from you to have worried about it :) they considered the answers to be simples enough to stay in the comments... You already said thanks, that's cool.